# Are the native iOS / Android key stores backed-up and can they be transfered?

Tags: android, ios, cryptography, android-keystore, enclave

The Android keystore system and iOS secure enclave can generate and store key pairs in the device for the app.

But how persistent are those key pairs? Will they be destroyed when the user unistalls the app? Are they transferred when the user changes their device?

Are they backed up into an iOS or Android specific server?

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the Android.
In an Android version below than 6 (Marshmallow), you should implement a [BackupAgent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent). The backup agent defines what data to back up and how to restore data.

Apps that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher are automatically enabled for Auto Backup. The Auto Backup feature is a file-based approach to backing up app data. While Auto Backup is simple to implement, you may consider using the Key/Value Backup feature if you have more specific needs for backing up data.

Here are some useful links: [link1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup) [link2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) [link3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup)

Comment: It might not related to normal app backup when it come to crypto key